# Running Eclipse Indigo on JDK7

Tags: eclipse, java-7

I tried to run Eclipse Indigo on a JDK7 on Windows 7 32bit, But Eclipse.exe complains with a dialog telling me that no java virtual machine was found after searching at the given location.

I've tried multiple times to set the -vm argument to be sure, it just doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: How did you set the -vm argument?

Comment: Have you checked the path? For me, the path is the following: `C:\projekte\setools-work\eclipse\indigo\ref\eclipse\eclipse.exe -data ws -vm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin\javaw.exe" -nl en`. As you can see, I had to include `"` for the path due to the spaces in the `x86` part.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify the JDK Installation

   Essentially, run `java -version` in the cmd, you should see the output.

   See http://alexsmail.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-install-jdk-7.html step 3
2. Check your Environment Variables (JAVA_HOME and path).

   See http://alexsmail.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-install-jdk-7.html step 0

Answer (score 0):

This is my eclipse.ini file which is in the same directory as eclipse.exe.  -vm must be on it's own line and the path to javaw.exe must be on it's own line.  I'm pretty sure I had to use forward slashes.  Also, -vmargs has to be the last thing in eclipse.ini.

```
    -vm
    C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/javaw.exe
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
    -Xms64m
    -Xmx512m
    -XX:PermSize=64m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```